# Get billing_address in paypal order

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Calling https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture in a python API with express checkut button:

In the response we are trying to get "**billing_address**" from payer account but we are not able.

We are managin "NO_SHIPPING" orders (no phisical products), so we need this address to process this data.

Is possible to get this billing_address in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PayPal, the default is that customer billing information is kept private by design, and so not available -- neither in PayPal.com nor in API responses.